# I am trying to wrap up a tkinter GUI by using pyinstaller. In the GUI I am using a . tcl style file but I can't figure out how to bring it along

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller

I have the following example GUI window. I would like to wrap this into an executable for my teammates to use. However, I cannot figure out how to include the "azure.tcl" file into the executable. Without this, it works, but I would like to try and bring it along.

```
window = tk.Tk()

window.tk.call("source","azure.tcl")

window.mainloop()
```

I tried the following:

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

I get the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't read file "azure.tcl": no such file or directory

I know I need to add the .tcl file along with it, but I cannot figure out how, could you please offer any advice?

Comment: You need to use `--add-data` to include the tcl file into the executabe.  Also look into [Runtime Information](https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) to learn how to look up file.

Comment: I tried this via: 
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=babel.numbers --add-data="C:\Path\to\azure.tcl;." test.py

however, I am still getting the same error that it cannot find the file.

Comment: Did you read the link in my last comment?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just not getting it. I am very new to programming so I'm what you'd call a moron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to include required files into the executable using `--add-data` option of PyInstaller.

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data="azure.tcl:." --add-data="theme:theme" test.py
```

Then you need to modify your code to load the required file from the temporary directory mentioned in [Runtime Information](https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) of PyInstaller.

```py
from pathlib import Path
...

# get the directory where the script file is
progdir = Path(__file__).parent

# function to get the absolute path of a file relative to the script file
def _path(relpath):
    return progdir / relpath

...

# load the required file using the above function
window.tk.call("source", _path("azure.tcl"))

...
```